# Proving bijection of Adjoint transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

> Assume $(V, \langle{}\cdot{},{}\cdot{}\rangle)_v$ and $(W, \langle {}\cdot{},{}\cdot{}\rangle)_w$ are finite dimensional inner product spaces. $T:V \rightarrow W$. Prove that $T^*T\colon V \rightarrow V$ is bijective.

I know how to prove the injection, but I am stuck on the surjection. Can I get a sketch of the proof or an idea of what I should look out for?

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis on $T$? That's obviously not true for $T=0$ for example. Also : a linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: $T:V \rightarrow W$. In this case, T is not a linear map

Comment: You might want to add this in the question.